# How to give Folder location on as input on this folder lock code in C?

Tags: c, windows

```
{
  char foldername[15];
  printf("Enter the foldername");
  scanf("%s", foldername);
  char command[100];
  sprintf(command, "cacls %s /e /p everyone:n",foldername);
  system(command);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the code, i want to manually input the location of the folder , but i don't know  how .

Comment: What is the problem?  What happens when you run this code, and what do you expect/want to happen?

Comment: it works ! but for code to work , i need the executable file at the target folder directory, but i need to simply execute the code from anywhere in computer to any folder in computer, by manually giving location as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can increase array size

```
char foldername[100];
```

and can give full path of folder.

Currently your giving foldername as "`stackoverflow_example`"

then you can give as

```
/home/user/projects/stackoverflow_example
```

it will work

AS YOUR comment:

```
it works ! but for code to work , i need the executable file at the 
target folder directory, but i need to simply execute the code 
from anywhere in computer to any folder in computer, by manually 
giving location as input.
```

**Now you can execute the code from anywhere in computer if you give full path.**

Comment: in windows folder path has \ instead of /  so try with that

Comment: @KamalKafkaesque how you give folder name?

Comment: i am giving the full path like f:\0th4r\awes

Comment: please help :) its urgently needed